# How to set the current working directory for a request in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know I can change the process directory using:

```
process.chdir('/temp/foo');
```

but I don't want to change the directory for all requests.

I would like to use a different working directory based on the request coming in.  For example if the request is for an image, I want to change the working directory to the image directory.  If the request is for an upload, I want to change the current working directory to the upload folder.

I have some other files in these folders specific to the type of request and it would be easier if I can set the current working directory for each request.

I do not want to change the working directory for all other requests being processed by the same server.  Each request's working directory should be specific to that request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with any path references just prepend the "working" directory:

```
function request1() {
  var workingDir = 'prefered/working/path';
  var path = path.resolve(workingDir, 'file.ext');
  var stats = fs.statSync(path);
}
```

Comment: So I have to use absolute paths everywhere?  I was hoping to set a current working directory and then just use relative paths from there.

Comment: You don't have to. `path.join(relativePath, 'file.ext');`

Comment: I see what you're doing and if there is no way to set a cwd on a request like you can on the process, I'll use this method which looks like it essentially resolves to the absolute path using some variables I would define and then use everywhere.